# Perl string parsing

Tags: string, perl, parsing

Friends...

I'm trying to parse this string in perl.

For last couple of classes I'm testing Oracle tns file and testing variations, this particular small if code is really taking time, could somebody please suggest?

Basically with the if statement, I'm trying to read tns file and put single value in hash reference till if statement gets expected result...

1. Get single alias value from the tns line
2. Get SID of that alias
3. Put distinct SId value into hash reference so as to connect database only once and not multiple times.

First if works but it connects couple of databases multiple times.

Code:

```
if /^(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(\.([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))*)(\s|,|=)/
{
  (/\(CONNECT_DATA\s+=\s+\(SID\s+=\s+(\w+\d+?)(\s+)?\)/)
    {  
      $hashref->{$1}="";
    }
}
```

Sample file (tnsfile.txt)

```
DB1.UK, DB2.UK =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB1.EU, DB2.CH =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB3.UK =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB3.US =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB4.UK.US, DB5.US =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db5))
  )
```

**Expected result**:

```
DB1.Uk

DB3.UK

DB4.UK.US
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex should be

```
/(^[A-Za-z0-9.]+)/
```

i.e. A string, anchored at the start of the line containing one or more alphanumeric characters or dots.  If you want to get more specific about ignoring lines where the string starts or ends with a dot you'd have to get more complex, but that is probably not needed if the file is a valid TNS file.

Here's a more complete regex that matches only valid strings

```
/^(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(\.([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))*)(\s|,|=)/
```

Comment: @Jim... that works like a charm ... Guys.. I'm seriously overwhelmed with this expert answer.. so with responses I was able to change my test code and connect databases mentioned in (SID = db1 .. db3 .. db5) ...    Unfortunately just now I saw tns files did have multiple duplicates of SID values ... so my code connects same database multiple times which really voids this whole test....Is there way to only connect same db once?

Comment: Jim, do you think there's a way to do this?  I'm not able to figure out ...this is really the last exercise holding up my test.  I tried using SID value and connect with SID but that's not the correct way since I should be using alias DB1.UK, DB4.UK.US ...Thanks much appreciate your efforts.

Comment: You must build a hash that maps tnsnames to connection parameters. This will allow you to detect duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by a single regex like demonstrated by Jim.  However, I'd advice you to break this up into steps

- Process your file in paragraph mode
- Separate out the beginning names.
- Split the names to get the first

Like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = ""; # Paragraph mode.

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name_list) = split /\s*=\s*/, $_, 2;
    my @names = split /,\s*/, $name_list;
    print $names[0], "\n";
}

__DATA__
DB1.UK, DB2.UK =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB3.UK =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB4.UK.US, DB5.US =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db5))
  )
```

Outputs:

```
DB1.UK
DB3.UK
DB4.UK.US
```

Or you can streamline that process and just use

```
my @first_names = $data =~ /^[^,]+/mg;
```

Comment: Miller ... I knew you will be there somewhere and will have great explanation as alaways... I'm becoming more of your follower...  :)