# Perl string parsing different variation

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

Experts... I'm creating another question in continuation with [my earlier query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942648/perl-string-parsing).... this question is different from earlier request so I thought better to create new thread instead of confusing experts answers.

Below code connects each alias in tnsfile to the database... 
1. Is there anyway I can limit each database connection only once and don't allow different alias connecting to the same database again?

I tried using hash but no able to fix this..

```
use strict;
use warnings;

if /^(([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)(\.([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*))*)(\s|,|=)/
{
    {  
      $hashref->{$1}="";
    }
}
```

Below regex can select each SID value from file but not able to combine with if...

```
(/\(CONNECT_DATA\s+=\s+\(SID\s+=\s+(\w+\d+?)(\s+)?\)/)
```

Sample file (tnsfile.txt)

```
DB1.UK, DB2.UK =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB1.EU, DB2.CH =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db1))
  )

DB3.UK =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB3.US =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db3))
  )

DB4.UK.US, DB4.US =
  (
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCAL = TCP))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = db4))
  )
```

Expected $hashref value:

```
DB1.UK  
DB3.UK  
DB4.UK.US
```

Comment: With my current if statement $hashref gets all the alias (DB1.Uk, DB1.EU, DB3.UK, DB3.US, DB4.UK.US) (ref: thanks to Jim Garrison) and connects eash SID = <db> multiple times ... so wondering how can I connect each database only once?

Comment: I've added a link to your previous question but it's still not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: thanks Tom... ohkie let me try again.  1. With my above code I'm able to extract all the aliases from the tnsfile.txt 2. Each aliases (DB1.Uk, DB1.EU, DB3.Uk, DB3.US, DB4.US.US) connects databases perfectly fine 3. Since couple of entries in tnsfile.txt have same SID value i.e. db1, db3, script connects this database multiple times which is of no use  4. So I'm trying to store alias with distinct SID value in hash.. and if that SID key already exist don't add another alias   .... in short my $hashref should have alias and should only connect db once

Comment: ( I dont care with what alias it connects) ... hopefully I explained it well.... I got the theoretical part but not able to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you caching your database handles?  It sounds like you are.

If so, you just need to create a new hash that relates SID to database handles.  Then you only optionally create a new handle if that SID hasn't already been loaded.

In psuedocode:

```
my %dbh_by_sid;

while (<DATA>) {
    my $sid = ...;

    my $dbh = $dbh_by_sid{$sid} ||= DBI->connect(...)
        or die "DB connect failed: $DBI::errstr";

    # ...
}
```

This way if that particular SID has already been connected to, it will reuse the same handle.

Comment: Thanks Miller it did helped.. sorry forgot to update this last week... appreciate your expert comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is far from a refined solution, and it breaks if the format of your tns file changes dramatically, but you could try something like this:

```
use strict;

my (%tns, %sid, $tns);

open IN, 'tnsfile.txt' or die;
while (<IN>) {
  if (/^([\w.]+)/) {
    ($tns) = $1;
  }

  if (/SID *= *([\w.]+)/) {
    $tns{$tns} = $1 unless ($sid{$1}++)
  }
}
close IN;

print join "\n", keys %tns;
```